# How to get line number for error using exception in Groovy (soapui/readyapi)

Tags: groovy, error-handling, exception, soapui

```
  //Code 1 
  log.info undefined
```

When we run the code 1 , we get below error in soapui/readyapi as

[image]

**please note :-** Line number is visible in error message

However to avoid this alert , we used try/catch to print this, so the above code is amended to below as code 2

```
//code 2
try
{
log.info undefined
}
catch(Exception e)
{
log.info e  
}
```

when we run the code 2 we get below results

```
Mon Mar 19 15:04:16 IST 2018:INFO:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: undefined for class: Script6
```

**Problem** :- How can we see the line number where the problem is just like we are able to see in code1

**Requirement** :- Our exception block should be able to tell problem is in which line.

Since its a small code we are able to know, Sometimes the code is having 100+ lines and its difficult to know where the exception is

Comment: Does it show the line number if you use `log.error`?

Comment: @tim_yates  No Only colour changes to red, Error message remains the same

Comment: How about `e.stackTrace.head().lineNumber`?

Comment: Sorry for the guessing, I'm not a soapui user :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Chris and Jeremy for solving my problem.

I have used the below solution using Chris answer with all full respect to your answer

```
try
{
log.info undefined
}
catch(Exception e)
{
log.error "Exception = " + e    

String str= e.getStackTrace().toString()

def pattern = ( str =~ /groovy.(\d+)./   )

log.error " Error at line number = " + pattern[0][1]
}
```

The reason i am using that answer is i can avoid an import in all my scripts.
I have used pattern matching to extract the line number as it always come like

```
(Script18.groovy:17),
```

so i have used the pattern 
    `/groovy.(\d+)./`

Now i get both the exception details and line number

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Building on @tim_yates answer of using `e.stackTrace.head().linenumber`:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils 

try {
    println undefined
} catch (Exception e) {
    StackTraceUtils.sanitize(e)
    e.stackTrace.head().lineNumber
}
```

Use `sanitize()` on your Exception to remove all the weird Groovy internal stuff from the stack trace for your Exception. Otherwise when you look at the first StackTraceElement, it probably won't be the one you want.

`deepSanitize()` is the same, but also applies the transform to all the nested Exceptions if there are any.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried that and it should be the accepted answer.  Never knew about sanitize, nice one Jeremy.

Comment: Yes the answer is accepted, it does what was asked. However i have used the answer using pattern matching. Please do see that answer and share your views @Jeremy

Comment: @jeremy sometimes i am getting error at  e.stackTrace.head().lineNumber .. Error = cannot access first() element from an empty Array

Answer (score 1):

You can use `log.info e.getStackTrace().toString();` to get the full stack trace.

However, it'll be hard to pick out the issue.  Here's my Groovy script....

```
try
{
log.info undefined
}
catch(Exception e)
{
log.info e.getStackTrace().toString();
}
```

Here's the trace....

Mon Mar 19 17:15:20 GMT 2018:INFO:[org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50), org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49), org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231), **Script21.run(Script21.groovy:3)**, com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:100), com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SourceFile:89), com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:154), com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:277), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source), java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)]

Note- the emboldened part.  It's line 3 and that is what I expected.  However, SoapUI must use internal numbering for scripts as I called the script "Dummy Groovy Script" and the stack trace says "Script21".

Anyhow, I do think you ought look at your Groovy script, 100+ lines in a Try seems a bit much and as you pint out, it's difficult to see the issue.

I'd suggest breaking it down into functions, or even better, call an Java class external to SoapUI, that has nice well-defined functions.

The SmartBear site describes how this can be done.  Plus, it remove a lot of the bloat from the SoapUI project file.

Comment: thanks and do check my answer that i have formed using yours @chris

Comment: sometimes e.getStackTrace().toString()returns null , whats the reason behind that.. in that case the solution does not work well

Comment: Do you mean in one particular script, sometimes it returns stack and sometimes it doesn’t?  Or, have you copied this catch section to other groovy scripts?

Comment: yes. One of my testcase got failed. I looked at groovy and run it once again and got an exception like this   Fri Mar 23 17:01:42 IST 2018:ERROR:java.util.NoSuchElementException: Cannot access first() element from an empty array... and able to replicate.. looks like getStacktrace is getting empty